# cannot sign in to Azure Visual Studio

Tags: azure

I have installed Azure SDK 2.8, Update 5 and App Insight Tools. After installing them, I am unable to Sign in to Azure using **Server Explorer**. It basically doesn't throw any error but it repeatedly comes back to the **Server Explorer** screen after entering the user name and password for Azure.

This is the first time I am using Visual Studio to log on to Azure. I am able to log on to Azure portal. The user name and password are definitely correct. It is something to do with Visual Studio.

Comment: Far fetched possibility: an issue with IE cookies.  Close VS, open IE, clear cookies and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by adding the following piece of code to **devenv.exe.config** file. This file can be found in 
**Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE**

```
<system.net>
                        <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true"/>
                        <settings>
                                    <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
                        </settings>
</system.net>
```